# How to request this url using python? http://localhost:35000/profile/launch/Profile_ID

Tags: python, networking, localhost, webrequest

How to request this url using python? http://localhost:35000/profile/launch/Profile_ID

The API endpoint lives at localhost:[PORTNUMBER]
35000 is the default port, but this can be changed by editing auth.json in C:/Users/%username%/incogniton/

Profile operations
localhost:35000/profile/launch/[PROFILE-ID] – launch a browser profile

localhost:35000/profile/launch/[PROFILE-ID]/local – launch a browser profile with local data

localhost:35000/profile/launch/[PROFILE-ID]/cloud – launch a browser profile with last saved cloud data

localhost:35000/profile/stop/[PROFILE-ID] – stop a browser profile

localhost:35000/profile/delete/[PROFILE-ID] – delete a browser profile

localhost:35000/profile/all – returns all browser profiles information

when i type the url in the browser nothing happens

Comment: Do you actually have a server running on port 35000?  Assuming you provided a profile ID that actually exists, the URL format is correct.  Does this work with `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: You could use the *get()* (HTTP GET) function of the *requests* module (once you've installed it). However, if your browser isn't responding then it's highly unlikely that trying with Python is going to help